# What is the difference between these two code blocks in d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I had thought that the d3.js `append` function returns the object appended to a selection, but I find the following two code blocks give different results:

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", fig_width)
        .attr("height", fig_height);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "graph")
        .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + graph_margin.left + "," + graph_margin.top + ")");
```

Which does not seem to translate the graph group, offsetting it by a left and top margin and:

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", fig_width)
        .attr("height", fig_height)
    .append("g")
        .attr("class", "graph")
        .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + graph_margin.left + "," + graph_margin.top + ")");
```

which does.

What don't I understand about the way this works in SVG / d3.js?

Comment: Both should give the same result. Can you post a complete example please that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Hmm, just tried [both snippets](http://plnkr.co/edit/RaPMhaBJzDLhDyPd6EeD?p=preview).  They produce the exact same results.  `<svg width="100" height="100"><g class="graph" transform="translate(30,30)"></g></svg>` and `<svg width="100" height="100"><g class="graph" transform="translate(30,30)"></g></svg>`

Comment: I'm guessing that you're using `svg` to append additional elements to -- keep in mind that in the first case, `svg` holds the SVG element and in the second the translated `g` element. So anything you append to `svg` in the first case wouldn't be translated (because it's not contained in the `g` element).

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff: Aha! I think I've got it, then. Looks like `svg` was a poor choice of variable name, then. In case it helps someone else, perhaps you could turn your comment into an answer for me to accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both code blocks should give exactly the same result.

I'm guessing that you're using `svg` to append additional elements to -- keep in mind that in the first case, `svg` holds the SVG element and in the second the translated `g` element. So anything you append to `svg` in the first case wouldn't be translated (because the new elements are not contained in the `g` element).